# Vue | Get all component data attributes

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get all of the Vue components data properties from within a mixin that I am using for my plugin.

I have got the plugin registering correctly and the mixin is actively working.

I have added a lifecycle hook from within the `Vue.mixin` which runs on the `created()` event.

I am trying to loop through all of the components data and assign it to a property within my plugin, this is because I want to manipulate all of the data in every single component in my application.

I have tried to do the following:

```js
Vue.mixin({
    created() {
        console.log(this.$options.data());
    }
})
```

But i get the result saying that data is not a function. However, calling within the `()` on the end of the data logs a function out which I can see the data within.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: The created method of the mixin is called before the created of the component. Might this be your problem?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? this does not seem like a good idea, the point of a `mixin` is to provide re-usability, the `mixin` already has access to the data property through `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `this.$data` instead:

```
Vue.mixin({
  created() {
    console.log(this.$data);
  }
});
```

**[>> DEMO on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/08mk70qrv?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&view=editor)**